# Play music/video from a phone to another phone

Tags: android, media, vlc

In Android, is there anyway to play a music/video file via another phone like Apple airplay?
I think vlc can create a media server via rtsp protocol for another phone to get the stream and play it. But perhaps only computer versions of vlc can create media server.